# Best way to update millions of records in SQL table with foreign keys

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I have a database with several tables, each holding millions of records.
Every year we receive a set of CSV files with which to update the tables. That's a refresh and not just an append.
Some of the tables have foreign keys back to the other tables.
To update the tables without the FK's, I'm simply truncating the database table, creating a new temporary table, load all the new data into the temp table and inserting that into the database table. All good and fairly quick.

The problem arises when I need to update data in a table that has FK's as I can no longer simply truncate the table so need a way to update the existing table rows.
I'm doing this via SQL update statements running in a loop, one row at a time. It works but takes some 13 days to process a couple of million records.
There must be a quicker way!

How can I quickly update multiple database table rows (say 3,500) at once, where each row has 8 columns that need updating ? 1 column is a FK, that plus 3 other columns do not change.

Comment: Just a thought, For performance issue your sql update should minimize using the operator `OR` yet used more accurate sql filter.

Comment: No OR operators. Just a few million loops.

Comment: This might not be the best way to to do it, but I've seen it done. You just drop the FKs before you start the process and add them back later. Could mess you up if you have bad data in your CSV file tho.

Comment: @Malcom, there's a benefit to place your million loops to a procedural script.

Comment: How much data changes between reloads? It may be more efficient to insert new data, update existing data that has modifications, and delete/disable data not in new data set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet is going to be the approach of:

1. Drop foreign key constraint.
2. Truncate foreign key table.
3. Truncate primary key table.
4. Insert into primary key table from the CSV file containing primary key data.
5. Insert foreign key data into a new temp table.
6. Inner Join foreign key temp table to the newly-populated primary key table on the related field.
7. Insert that join result into final foreign key table.
8. Re-create the foreign key on the foreign key table.

And with a bit of dynamic SQL, you could create a stored proc and pass the table names, file names, and foreign key names as parameters into the proc.  Then just rinse and repeat for each set of related tables.

Even without a stored proc, it should take much less than 13 days :)

**UPDATED WITH A POSSIBLE EXAMPLE**

```
ALTER TABLE [SecondaryTable] DROP CONSTRAINT [NameOfForeignKey]

TRUNCATE TABLE [SecondaryTable]

TRUNCATE TABLE [PrimaryTable]

BULK INSERT [PrimaryTable]
FROM 'C:\PrimaryCSVfile.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR =',', ROWTERMINATOR ='\n', FIRSTROW = 1)

-- [TempTableSecondary] is a structural copy of [SecondaryTable]
CREATE TABLE [TempTableSecondary] (column1, column2, ..., columnX)

BULK INSERT [TempTableSecondary]
FROM 'C:\SecondaryCSVfile.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR =',', ROWTERMINATOR ='\n', FIRSTROW = 1)

INSERT INTO [SecondaryTable]
SELECT [TempTableSecondary].*
FROM [TempTableSecondary]
    INNER JOIN [PrimaryTable] ON [TempTableSecondary].PrimaryKeyFieldName = [PrimaryTable].ForeignKeyFieldName

ALTER TABLE [SecondaryTable] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [NameOfForeignKey] FOREIGN KEY([PrimaryKeyFieldName])
REFERENCES [PrimaryTable] ([ForeignKeyFieldName])

ALTER TABLE [SecondaryTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [NameOfForeignKey]

DROP TABLE [TempTableSecondary]
```

Comment: So there's no bad effect arising from dropping FK's then?  Seems a silly question but I've never been in this situation before.

Comment: There would definitely be repercussions if your tables are highly transactional.  Will these be active at the time?  Inserts, deletes, updates outside of your own updating?  Or are they more static in nature?

Comment: Sorry, should have clearer. I meant dropping/reinstating FK's from an inactive database. The entire database will be offline to users for the duration.  No other actions undertaken apart from my app and that is only dealing with one table at a time.

Comment: If that's the case, then dropping and re-creating is definitely the way to go.  There's no performance hit to worry about, and as long as you are validating the relationship before inserting (via the Inner Join step), you'll ensure the referential integrity.

Comment: Thanks McCee. Just to get this clear in my head, following your list above, I'm doing this:    
1. Truncate and rebuild primary key table (also has the foreign Key column)    
2. Drop foreign key from 2nd table    
3. Truncate and rebuild 2nd table    
4. --- inner join stuff ---    
5. reinstate foreign key back to primary table    
    
Step 4 has me lost. Is that just your way of loading the new data back into the 2nd table?  If so, I was doing this via a SQL INSERT command.    
Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Check out my modified answer - added some example code.  The jist is that you want to pre-validate your secondary table data in case there are records that don't correctly relate back to the primary table.